# Batch process in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, batch-processing

I create a custom console command in symfony2. This command will call the api to find fit jobs for all users. then I'll get a error like this.
My code is like:

```
 $em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager('default');
            $user = $em->getRepository('EnsUserBundle:User')->findAll();
                foreach ($user as $user) 
                {
                    .....
                    $em->flush();
                }
            }
        }
```

[image]

Then I want to clear the entitymanager for each user.

```
$em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager('default');
                $user = $em->getRepository('EnsUserBundle:User')->findAll();
                    foreach ($user as $user) 
                    {
                        .....
                        $em->flush();
                        $em->clear();
                    }
                }
            }
```

It will lead to a error:
[image]
Then i try to use the batch process:

```
$em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager('default');
        $user = $em->getRepository('EnsUserBundle:User')->findAll();
        $iterableResult = $em->getRepository('EnsUserBundle:User')->findAll()->iterate();
        while (($row = $iterableResult->next()) !== false) 
        {
            foreach ($user as $user) 
            {
                .....
                $em->flush();
                $em->clear();
            }
            $em->detach($row[0]);
        }
    }
```

But it leads to an error
[image]

So, do you have any good advices?
Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try :

- Increase the maximum memory a script consumes inside php : <kbd>**php.ini**</kbd>
  `memory_limit = 512M`
- Flush your objects when it reaches XX items (ex: each 100 items). You can clear your manager each time you flush it.

Comment: Thank your for answering me. But as you see in the second screenshot. Every time i try to clear it, i will get this error. Do you know why?

Comment: I suggested that you clear the entityManager each XX time (bulk processing). Why do you need to use the iterate() function and involve  it into 2 loops ?

Comment: Maybe i dont need. Because i saw this http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine2-batch-processing.html#mass-object-processing. So i think maybe that could help me.